# Add user to Active Directory through php

Tags: active-directory

Following is the code I am using to add user in Active Directory

```
<?php
$ldapConn = ldap_connect('ldap://xxx.xx.x.xx:389');
ldap_set_option($ldapConn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

ldap_bind( $ldapConn, 'xx.xx@xx.xx', 'xxxx');

$dn_user='CN=testLDAP,OU=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx';

$ldaprecord['cn'] = "testLDAP";
$ldaprecord['givenName'] = "testLDAP";  
$ldaprecord['sn'] = "testLDAP";
$ldaprecord['sAMAccountName'] = "testLDAP";
$ldaprecord['UserPrincipalName'] = "testLDAP@xx.xx";
$ldaprecord['displayName'] = "testLDAP";
$ldaprecord['name'] = "testLDAP";
$ldaprecord['UserAccountControl'] = "544";
$ldaprecord['objectclass'][0] = 'top';
$ldaprecord['objectclass'][1] = 'person';
$ldaprecord['objectclass'][2] = 'organizationalPerson';
$ldaprecord['objectclass'][3] = 'user';
$ldaprecord['mail'] = "testLDAP@abc.com";

$add = ldap_add($ldapConn, $dn_user, $ldaprecord);

    if($add) {
        echo "User successfully added";
    } else {
        echo "User not added";
    }
ldap_close($ldapConn);
?>
```

But I am getting the error saying

**Warning: ldap_add() [function.ldap-add]: Add: Can't contact LDAP server**

What's wrong with my code, please help me..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You must be connecting under SSL/TLS to be able to create users or set/change passwords, all other Active Directory functions can be executed under a plain text connection.

To make your life easier, I suggest you look into this 3rd party library : http://adldap.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am able to create a user through ldap_add() without using any SSL/TLS from my local environment. And I have uploaded the same program into the linux environment and executed. Now the network got down for every request and getting above exception in log file